# «Comme pas un» et «comme pas deux»

Tags: expressions, usage, étymologie, registre-familier, synonymes

Les deux sont attestés pour indiquer l’unicité, la singularité, l’incomparabilité du sujet considéré. Affublés de la mention *Familier* dans les dictionnaires usuels *(Le Petit Robert, le Trésor de la langue française, etc.)*, ils se comprennent assez bien l’un et l’autre et certains écrivains y ont eu recours.

- **Comme pas un :** par ellipse, comme pas un autre.
- **Comme pas deux :** On ne saurait en trouver un deuxième comme celui-ci.

C’est intéressant de constater qu’**un** et **deux** se rejoignent en cette structure où ils deviennent pour ainsi dire synonymes *(un cas unique ?)*.

Un [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+pas+un%2Ccomme+pas+deux&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccomme%20pas%20un%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccomme%20pas%20deux%3B%2Cc0) semble montrer que *« comme pas un »* est à la fois le plus ancien et le plus répandu, mais que [l’écart se ressere](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=comme+pas+un%2F%28comme+pas+un%2Bcomme+pas+deux%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28comme%20pas%20un%20/%20%28comme%20pas%20un%20%2B%20comme%20pas%20deux%29%29%3B%2Cc0).

À la lumière de ceci, je m’interroge sur les raisons qui ont éventuellement permis l’émergence de *« comme pas deux »,* et lui ont conféré un statut presque équivalent à *« comme pas un »*. Y aurait-il une explication simple et crédible, ou n’est-ce qu’un hasard aux allures surprenantes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'imagine que ce développement est dû à l'ellipse que tu viens d'identifier.

Avec le temps, un élément élidé est généralement oublié. Je pense par exemple à « Speak of the devil » en anglais. Personne ne tente de terminer cet énoncé et deux personnes donneraient probablement deux versions différentes du reste.

Une fois cette étape achevée, soit l'expression reste figée sans que personne ne se fasse de souci au sujet du non-sens, soit de petits « amendements » se produisent pour y comprendre la logique. Je suppose que les expressions qui ne sont qu’à deux pas d'être compréhensibles y sont plus susceptibles.

Vu que *comme pas un* semble être absurde sans l'élément élidé — « Comme pas un ? Mais en voici un ! » — il se peut que les gens corrigent « un » (pour ainsi dire) en cherchant un minimum acceptable pour la comparaison ... :)